# Keep two elements tied together when screen resizes (bootstrap4)

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have the following snippet of code (using bootstrap4 and css), which in normal screens it shows correctly (as in the first screenshot)

```
    `<div class="col-1 col-sm-2 col-lg-1" style="float:left;">  
        <table class="table">
          <thead style=" ">
            <tr>
              <p style="height:100%; border-left: 3px solid #2a93fc;">
                <h2 class="general_info" style="transform: rotate(270deg); margin-top:-150px; margin-left:30px ">2018<h2>
              </p>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>`
```

[image]

But when I resize the screen into medium, small then the 2018 label moves upper as in the second screenshot:

[image]

How can I keep these two elements tied together?

Comment: Why are you putting those parts into a table? That's not tabular data, is it?

Comment: Nope. I only put the "2018" in a table cause somehow I wanted to create a "solid" structure of a table cell which will resize properly (its content).

Comment: HTML tables pretty much never resize properly because they aren't designed for that.

Comment: Hmm. What do you suggest? I just want the date with this horizontal line.

Comment: What should happen on the smallest screens? Remember, the smallest screen is just 320px wide.

Comment: I just checked and it would actually fit OK on a 320px wide screen if the circles are that size.

Comment: Well I just need to have the date next to the line. But actually the date goes upwards (as in screenshot).